# Count where is not null in Spark Scala

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I'm making an analysis using spark with scala, one of the columns should bring the count of that column not considering the null values, however its counting the null values too despite i've passed .isnotnull in the count, the whole piece of the code:

```
val df2: DataFrame = df.groupBy(col("ato")).agg(max(datediff(lit(dt_ref), col("data_entrada"))).alias("max_data_entrada"), count("id_licenca").alias("count_id_licenca"), count(when(col("processo_situacao").isNotNull, col("processo_situacao"))).alias("count_situacao"))
```

the parte that is giving me this problem:

```
count(when(col("processo_situacao").isNotNull, col("processo_situacao"))).alias("count_situacao"))
```

Ive tried other methods, like using count(when(col("processo_situacao").isNotNull, 1).otherwise(0)).alias("count_situacao")), but its just dont work

How to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the null values before doing the aggregation and doing the count.

```
df.filter(col("processo_situacao").isNotNull)
  .groupBy(col("ato"))
  .agg()
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to count with condition you can use SUM with condition and add one when condition is true

```
sum(when(condition, 1)).as("countWithCondition")
```

Sample full code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SparkSession, DataFrame}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val data = Seq(
  ("A", "2023-07-15", "2023-07-01", 1, "Active"),
  ("A", "2023-07-15", "2023-07-05", 2, "Inactive"),
  ("B", "2023-07-15", "2023-07-02", 3, "Active"),
  ("B", "2023-07-15", "2023-07-06", 4, null),
  ("A", "2023-07-15", "2023-07-10", 5, "Active")
)

val columns =
  Seq("ato", "dt_ref", "data_entrada", "id_licenca", "processo_situacao")
val df: DataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF(columns: _*)

val df2: DataFrame = df
  .groupBy(col("ato"))
  .agg(
    max(datediff(lit("dt_ref"), col("data_entrada"))).alias("max_data_entrada"),
    count("id_licenca").alias("count_id_licenca"),
    sum(when(col("processo_situacao").isNotNull, 1)).alias("count_situacao")
  )

df2.show()
```

Output:

```
+---+----------------+----------------+--------------+
|ato|max_data_entrada|count_id_licenca|count_situacao|
+---+----------------+----------------+--------------+
|  A|            null|               3|             3|
|  B|            null|               2|             1|
+---+----------------+----------------+--------------+
```